# Why are my aloe’s leaves flattening?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, indoors, aloe

In the past few weeks some of my aloe’s leaves are becoming flat. What is wrong with it? Is there anything I can do? [image: here’s a photo].

Answer (score 1):

they're getting dry, they like to tap the water table.

make sure there's enough water for the deep taproot to drink all the time

Comment: How much water should I give and how long should I wait until I water again?

Comment: It's not a recipe. Water until it flows out the bottom of the pot. When the top 2 inches of soil is mostly dry, water again. Watering frequency depends on temperature, humidity, sun exposure, etc.

Comment: You can just allow 2 inches of water to stay in the bottom of a 6" pot.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience i will say this is due to sunlight, Location of this Aloe is not bright enough, these God's beautiful creation like to have a bright light. I have a full grown Aloe vera, When i changed my residence, I had to place my Aloe vera on stairs which was bright but not bright enough for Aloe. Now i moved them on the roof and now they are happy , they good fresh air and good amount of sunlight.

Water them once a month in winter and summer maybe every week if you move it outside otherwise every 2 week if you keep them inside.